# Changing a list layout on mobile devices only using css

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have the following code on a wordpress site. I can't change the html, so, only using css @media queries I would like to make the list go from 4 per row on a desktop, down to 2 per row in a viewport of under 767px.

Is that possible?

```css
.recent_view_prod ul.product_list_widget li {
  width: 22%;
  margin-right: 2%;
}
.recent_view_prod ul.product_list_widget li img {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.recent_view_prod ul.product_list_widget li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.recent_view_prod span.product-title {
  display: none;
}

a:hover > .attachment-shop_thumbnail + span {
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="wpb_widgetised_column wpb_content_element recent_view_prod">
  <div class="wpb_wrapper">
    <div id="woocommerce_recently_viewed_products-3" class="widget woocommerce widget_recently_viewed_products">
      <h3 class="widget-title element-title">Recently Viewed Products</h3>
      <ul class="product_list_widget">
        <li>
          <a href="http://uc.petekirkwood.co.uk/shop/opulent-bloom-card-holder/" title="Opulent Bloom Card Holder">
            <img width="180" height="135" src="http://uc.petekirkwood.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/TedBaker_CardHolderOpulentBloom_2-180x135.jpg" class="attachment-shop_thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="TedBaker_CardHolderOpulentBloom_2"> <span class="product-title">Opulent Bloom Card Holder</span>
          </a>
          
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="http://uc.petekirkwood.co.uk/shop/store-ms/" title="Store-M's Nesting Food Boxes">
            <img width="180" height="135" src="http://uc.petekirkwood.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/StoreMs1-180x135.jpg" class="attachment-shop_thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="StoreMs1"> <span class="product-title">Store-M's Nesting Food Boxes</span>
          </a>
          
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="http://uc.petekirkwood.co.uk/shop/happy-jackson-crackers-tin/" title="Happy Jackson Crackers Tin">
            <img width="180" height="135" src="http://uc.petekirkwood.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/HappyJCrackersTIn-180x135.jpg" class="attachment-shop_thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="HappyJCrackersTIn"> <span class="product-title">Happy Jackson Crackers Tin</span>
          </a>
         
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="http://uc.petekirkwood.co.uk/shop/happy-jackson-snack-box-set/" title="Happy Jackson Snack Box Set">
            <img width="180" height="135" src="http://uc.petekirkwood.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/SnackBoxSetx4_2-180x135.jpg" class="attachment-shop_thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="SnackBoxSetx4_2"> <span class="product-title">Happy Jackson Snack Box Set</span>
          </a>
          
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.recent_view_prod ul.product_list_widget li {
    width: 45%;
    margin: 0 2%;
}`

using this under `768px` wil do the trick, however your images will stretch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `float: left` in the under 767px and increase the width of `<li>`.

For example try this code:

```
.recent_view_prod ul.product_list_widget li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 2%;
  width: 40%;
}
```

Comment: `float:left` won't center the `img`.

Comment: Thanks - that's done the trick! you learn something new every day!

Answer (score 0):

It's entirely possible to do this. You could have your default code as something like this (mobile first approach) - you may need to play around with the percentage to make sure the two fit side by side:

```
.recent_view_prod ul.product_list_widget li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 47%;
  margin-right: 2%;
}
.recent_view_prod ul.product_list_widget li img {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.recent_view_prod ul.product_list_widget li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.recent_view_prod span.product-title {
  display: none;
}

a:hover > .attachment-shop_thumbnail + span {
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
}
```

and then add a media query at the end (again adjust the min-width to suit you) that brings them back to the four column layout as you currently have it, as the screen widens.

```
@media (min-width: 25em){
    .recent_view_prod ul.product_list_widget li {
       width: 22%;
    }
}
```